# Laravel: How to query a json column for multiple conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a simple json table containing an array of values:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

I'm trying to query this table by multiple conditions:

1. Must contain the value `2`
2. Must contain atleast 3 of the other values, it does not matter which ones

This is what I currently have:

```
$data= Model::whereJsonContains('my_column', [2])->get();
```

This works for condition 1, now I can't seem to figure out how to include condition 2 as well.

Comment: Topically related: [Count JSON Array in Query Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59206533/2943403) and [Eloquent: Getting sum of values (json property) based on weekday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68137162/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON array has *unique values*, you can use [`whereJsonLength`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#json-where-clauses) to count the size of the JSON array like below:

```
$data = Model::whereJsonContains('my_column', 2)
              ->whereJsonLength('my_column', '>', 3)
              ->get();
```